# How can I show time as HH:MM format?

Tags: reactjs, polaris

I am showing time using **TextField** component in **React Polaris**.

```
<TextField type="time" label="Time" value="13:25" onChange={this.onChangeTime)} />
```

Currently, it shows as **01:25:00 PM**.

Is there any way to show only **HH:MM** format?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed by adding `step="0"`

```
<TextField type="time" label="Time" step="0" value="13:25" onChange={this.onChangeTime)} />
```

You can check here:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/peaceful-worker-2nzsm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark